# Change the author of the comment from the admin control panel.

Tags: wordpress, comments, author

How can I change the author of the comment from the admin control panel?

A more detailed explanation, how can I change the value of the user_id column (which is located in the `wp_comment` table) from the admin control panel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to edit your comments by logging into your wordpress dashboard and clicking on the Comments tab on the left.

Here you will see all of your comments, simply highlight over the comment, and click on the edit button. Here you can change the authors name, email, website and the actual comment.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I want to choose the user from a dropdown menu like posts!

Thank you.